# htaccess won't work out

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have `htaccess` with these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
rewritecond %{http_host} ^www.example.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
RewriteRule ^admin/$ admin.php [L]
RewriteRule ^home/$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)-([0-9]+)/$ index.php?p=news&id=$2
```

My url is:`http://example.com/news/why-do-not-you-love-me-1/#main`
Test on [htaccess.mwl.be](http://htaccess.mwl.be/), it return `http://l2baium.com/index.php?p=news&id=1#main` with which works on my site.
But on my side, it still doesn't realize it. I restarted apache2 on my Ubuntu 14.02 three times. But there is no light for it.
Could someone tell me why?
Thanks.

P/s: My system's using php 5.5.x

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being stupid. But i did not know that i must setup so that Php would parse `htaccess` file until last night.
Sorry everyone.